# ASP.net Package and Deployement Configuration Difference?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

what is the difference between in configuration (i.e Release,Debug, All configuration) in asp.net package and deployment?

Answer (score 0):

Whatever you want it to be?

Debug usually has un-optimized code and debug symbols.  Release turns that off.  You can change these values to whatever you want.